# Passing multiple Id's from Datatable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, datatable

Is this possible to pass multiple Id's from DataTable button?
My project is ASP.NET MVC Web Api. I need three Id's to pass to my function. I will show you in my code what I mean.

```
                $.ajax({
                url: "/Api/Products",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                   var MyTable =  $('#productTable').DataTable({

                        'paging' : true,
                        'sort': true,
                        'searching': true,

          columns: [

          { 'data': 'ProductId' ,'autoWidth': true },
          { 'data': 'ProductName', 'autoWidth': true },
          { 'data': 'CountryId', 'autoWidth': true },
          { 'data': 'GroupId' , 'autoWidth': true },



{
```

//How to here pass three Id's? Right now I just only pass one Id and that's //ProductId

```
{
  'data': 'data', 'searchable': false, 'sortable': false, 'width': '150px', 'render': function (data) {
 return '<Button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return getByID(' + data.productId, data.GroupId, data.countryId + ')">Edit</button>';
 }
    },

    getByID(ProductId,CountryId,GroupId)
    {

    // some data
    // But How to get CountryId and GroupId from DataTable button
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass on object as your parameter.  You'd have to create your param as the object type to accept it.
For example:
    'data': 'ProductId'+ ??? + ???,

```
var someObject = {
    ProductId = whatever,
    NextId = whatever,
    ThirdId = whatever
 }
```

Then digest the object into a model on server side to do what you need.

Comment: thank you for your response but it's difficult to me to understand what you mean. I'am new to this staff, would be grateful if you show me how to solve this problem.

Comment: @JonasWillander so what it looks like is that you are trying to pass three parameters into your GetById method/function.  Instead of passing 3 individual parameters you'll want to pass an object, within an object.  Your fields exist on the get, your datatable has 4 rows.  Pass the data object as the parameter not the 3 individual fields.  So where you have 'data': "productId' + ?? + ??, pass 'data': data (this should include your fields needed.  This is the main object so in the getByID, pull out your parameters from the object.

Comment: 'data': 'data, 'width': '50px', 'render': function (data) {
return '<Button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return getByID(' + data + '??? + ???)">Edit</button>';
}

    getByID(data.productId, data.GroupId, data.countryid)
    {

Comment: Do you mean like this?  {
                                'data': 'data', 'searchable': false, 'sortable': false, 'width': '150px', 'render': function (data) {
                                    return '<Button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return getByID(' + data.productId, data.GroupId, data.countryId + ')">Edit</button>';
                                }
                            }

Comment: I have updated Column part, can you please se there b/c it's easy to read the code

Comment: Sorry for the delay @JonasWillander yes, that looks much better.  However you have to make sure the data is populated with the values that you want.  It looks good though.